# Mousemove event target not applying to headers and other targets not in position?

Tags: devtools, mousemove

Hi I am making a clone of the browser inspect page tool. When hovering over an element it adds an overlay. I'm doing it to make a customizable web scraper for my job. It's basically working not, but it is not firing on most page headers even if they are just in a div. I believe it has something to do with the positioning.

Does anyone know what might be the issue?